# "Показать ещё" N-элементов из Array-Like объекта

Tags: jquery

Допустим, что есть Array-Like объект, структура в котором:

```
let array = [{
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "Details",
    "date": "31.03.2017 17:13"
},
{
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "Details",
    "date": "30.03.2017 17:23"
},
{
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "Details",
    "date": "29.03.2017 17:33"
}];
```

Таких элементов может быть несколько сотен или тысяч. Я ищу плагин, который выводил бы на страницу эти данные в размере 10 штук, например. И чтобы внизу страницы была кнопка "Показать ещё N элементов". Все плагины, которые я нашёл, работают в основном с серверной частью. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужный мне плагин.

P.S. - это фича называется, вроде, **infinite scroll**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Плагины здесь вообще не нужны.

```js
'use strict';

let array = [
    {'title': 'Статья 1', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '31.03.2017 17:13'},
    {'title': 'Статья 2', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '30.03.2017 17:23'},
    {'title': 'Статья 3', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '29.03.2017 17:33'},
    {'title': 'Статья 4', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '31.03.2017 17:13'},
    {'title': 'Статья 5', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '30.03.2017 17:23'},
    {'title': 'Статья 6', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '29.03.2017 17:33'},
    {'title': 'Статья 7', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '31.03.2017 17:13'},
    {'title': 'Статья 8', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '30.03.2017 17:23'},
    {'title': 'Статья 9', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '29.03.2017 17:33'},
    {'title': 'Статья 10', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '31.03.2017 17:13'},
    {'title': 'Статья 11', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '30.03.2017 17:23'},
    {'title': 'Статья 12', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '29.03.2017 17:33'},
    {'title': 'Статья 13', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '31.03.2017 17:13'},
    {'title': 'Статья 14', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '30.03.2017 17:23'},
    {'title': 'Статья 15', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '29.03.2017 17:33'},
    {'title': 'Статья 16', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '31.03.2017 17:13'},
    {'title': 'Статья 17', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '30.03.2017 17:23'},
    {'title': 'Статья 18', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '29.03.2017 17:33'},
    {'title': 'Статья 19', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '31.03.2017 17:13'},
    {'title': 'Статья 20', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '30.03.2017 17:23'},
    {'title': 'Статья 21', 'description': 'Details', 'date': '29.03.2017 17:33'}
];

let itemsContainer;
let nextItem = 0;

function initPage()
{
    const scroller = document.getElementById('infinitescroller');
    itemsContainer = scroller.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
    loadmore();
}

function loadmore()
{
    const nextBunchFirstItem = nextItem + 10;
    for(let i = nextItem; i < nextBunchFirstItem && i < array.length; ++i)
    {
        const record = array[i];
    
        const recordElement = document.createElement('div');
        itemsContainer.appendChild(recordElement);
    
        const titleElement = document.createElement('h2');
        titleElement.textContent = record['title'];
        recordElement.appendChild(titleElement);
        
        const descriptionElement = document.createElement('p');
        descriptionElement.textContent = record['description'];
        recordElement.appendChild(descriptionElement);
        
        const dateElement = document.createElement('time');
        dateElement.textContent = record['date'];
        var parts = record['date'].match(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})/);
        dateElement.setAttribute(
            'datetime',
                new Date(
                    Date.UTC(+parts[3], parts[2] - 1, +parts[1], +parts[4], +parts[5])
                ).toISOString()
            );
        recordElement.appendChild(dateElement);
    }
    
    nextItem = nextBunchFirstItem;
}
```

```css
#infinitescroller
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 3pt;
    padding: 7pt;
    text-align: center
}

#infinitescroller .content
{
    text-align: left
}

#infinitescroller .content > div
{
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 3pt;
    margin-bottom: 7pt;
    padding: 6pt
}

#infinitescroller .content > div > h2
{
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0pt
}

#infinitescroller .content > div > p,
#infinitescroller .content > div > time
{
    margin-left: 7pt;
}

#infinitescroller .content > div > time
{
    font-style: italic
}

#infinitescroller button
{
    margin: 7pt auto 0pt auto
}
```

```html
<body onload="initPage()">
    <div id="infinitescroller">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <button onclick="loadmore()">Показать ещё десять элементов</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Как видите, для вставки блока требуется меньше ста строк хорошо форматированного кода с вертикальными отступами и разбивкой некоторых строк на несколько. При этом около половины кода занимает описание исходных данных для отображения. После минификации же код станет ещё меньше, причём значительно.